# How to get JavaScript .value working in PHP echo

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I got a question to a JavaScript code. I got an HTML form:

```
<form action="getValue.php" method="post" id="myform">
    <input type="text" id="mybox" name="mybox" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I want to alert the value by clicking submit button. For this I use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myform').submit(function(event){
        alert(document.getElementById('mybox').value);
    });
});
```

If I type in for example "123" it alerts "123". Okay, this works. Now I want to run this JavaScript code in PHP `echo`. For this I tried this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo "<script>alert(document.getElementById('mybox').value);</script>";
}
```

If I now type in "123" it returns " ". So nothing returns. Can someone explain me why this is or how to fix this?

Cheers

**EDIT:** It is all in the same file (getValue.php)

Comment: How should that work? When you post the data the form is rendered again and the value is gone.

Comment: what's the problem with `$_POST['mybox']` the same thing you tried to do.

Comment: I have to say: I am new to PHP and JavaScript, this is to test for me. If I write `$(document).ready` function nothing happen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your text box will not be populated when the page has been reloaded.

Try echo'ing the actual post value.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo "<script>alert('" . $_POST['mybox'] . "');</script>";
}
```

**Edit:**

As you pointed out that you were new to PHP & JavaScript I thought I'd mention that you seem to be using half jQuery and half non-jQuery...

For example instead of using

```
document.getElementById('mybox').value
```

You can use

```
$('#mybox').val();
```

Comment: Probably want to quote it unless we're only using 123

Comment: It doesn't work with `$('#mybox').val();` but your first code works perfect :) Thank you! Just wondering why it doesn't work with `jQuery` `.val()` function

Comment: @Roman - it wouldn't work the way you were previously doing it, even when using `$('#mybox').val();`, I was just pointing out that if you were to get the value of a DOM element, you may aswell continue using jQuery instead of mixing it up. It's not wrong just a point of advice.

Comment: No worries, feel free to mark this as the answer if it's helped.

Comment: I will, but I have to wait 2 minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Data has been submitted to ' . $_POST['mybox'] . '");</script>';
```